# Difference between struts URL patterns types?

Tags: struts2

What is the difference struts2 URL pattern below types?

```
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>     
<url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern> and <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> ?
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the differences aren't obvious; do you have a specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  // for all requests

<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>  // for all requests which contains extinction .do

<url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern> // for all contains path like struts/
```

Comment: Struts2 Extinction ? I hope not :>